# Java Kryo weird behavior depending on String length

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kryo

I'm serializing an object into a file using Kryo 2.22 library (I'm using the UnsafeInput/Output for performance).

My object contains many fields including 1 String. When this string contains up to ~35 characters, no problem. Once I double this to ~70 characters, I get the following exception when deserializing from the file:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 63
Serialization trace:
handCards (vo.ShortHandVO)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
```

When doubling the String's length, I just copied the initial content (i.e. no additional / special characters introduced).

My first guess was thus that it is related to the increased object size: I doubled the Kryo buffer size but the exception is still thrown.

I have now lost hours finding the problem and I'm getting hopeless. Any hint / suggestion would be very much appreciated !

Many thanks,
Thomas

**UPDATE:** I finally found the issue: I was serializing a child class and deserializing the parent class. What didn't help is that Kryo inconsistently throws an exception (in this case, it was dependent on the String's size)

Comment: The can happen because a sequence of bytes can be "semi-correctly" interpreted many ways depending on context. You don't get an exception until Kryo knows its wrong. Once I managed to deserialise one object into a mad version of a completely different object by luck (I was experimenting with blasting though exceptions at the time though). I assume you're using kryo.readObject & kryo.writeObject. kryo.readClassAndObject & kryo.writeClassAndObject pick up on these things quicker (but I presume have a little more overhead).

Comment: P.s. when you've found an answer to your own question its usual to put it as an answer rather than editing it into the question